# $q.all returns state instead of values - why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

Here is the code:

```
$q.all($q.when(3), $q.when(5)).then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

The output is the following:

```
{"$$state":{"status":1,"value":3}}
```

The manual states that:

> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of
>   values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key
>   in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a
>   rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same
>   rejection value.

So I'm confused why values are not returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$q.all` accepts an array or an object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all), so if you change it to this it should work:

```
$q.all([$q.when(3), $q.when(5)]).then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```